# Ошибка чтения файла формата .dat

Tags: python, база-данных, csv

Не могу прочесть файл формата dat. 
Пробовал такой код:

```
import csv

with open('seg01.dat') as dat_file, open('seg01.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for line in dat_file:
        row = [field.strip() for field in line.split('|')]
        if len(row) == 6 and row[3] and row[4]:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 163: character maps to <undefined>
```

Пример данных по ссылке с ресурса медицинских данных Physionet 
https://physionet.org/content/wctecgdb/1.0.1/

Хотелось бы получить табличные данные в `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: Логично, что выдаёт ошибку, файл же в формате waveform-database, а не csv.

Comment: Прекрасно, а как тогда прочитать формат waveform-database?